# Confusions with Symbol "=" in Mathematics

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology, first-order-logic

I am having this question because of the axiom of equality:
\begin{equation}
\forall x \forall y \left(x = y \longrightarrow \forall z\left(z \in x \longleftrightarrow z \in y\right)\right).
\end{equation}
It seems to me that $x = y$ is nothing but $\forall z\left(z \in x \longleftrightarrow z \in y\right)$. However, the equality symbol is defined in some formal first-order logical systems. For instance, the fitch system is equipped with the symbol "$=$" and replacement of equal symbols is a rule in the system. I am wondering if "$=$" is really needed in a formal system? If not, is it possible to deduce the rule of substitution of equal symbols from without?

P.S. This symbol confuses me sometimes, as it takes a little effort to realize if the writing "x = y" means the predicate "x = y" from the language or the predicate "$\left(x,y\right) \in =$", where "$=$" is a relation, a set of 2-tuples defined on a set (real numbers, for instance). For example, the property of "anti-symmetry" for real numbers is stated as follows:

> For all $r,s \in \mathbb{R}$, if $r \leq_{\mathbb{R}} s$ and $s \leq_{\mathbb{R}} r$, then $r = s$.

Here, should we think of "$=$" as the equivalence relation "$=_{\mathbb{R}}$", or, as the one from the language itself (although in the case of real numbers, equality as a predicate and equality as a equivalence relation are closely related)? If it is the former case, then does it mean that "antisymmetry" on a set $S$ relies on a well-defined equivalence relation "$=_{S}$" on a set $S$ in general?

Comment: You can't reduce equality in FOL, you need second order for it. Liebniz's Identity. It's much more practical for Fitch-like Natural deduction systems to take equality as fundamental-ish.

Comment: "=" is just as redundant in set theory as the operation symbol "+" is for  $\mathbb N$. It's just a shorthand. Nothing more.

Comment: You certainly can develop set theory taking equality as a defined predicate via the equality axiom as you have stated it.

Comment: I don't really like this symbol as there is another equality "=" defined as a set of 2-tuples (better be called equivalence relations). It confuses me sometimes. So set theory can be viewed as a first-order system without "=", and equality substitution is a theorem, right?